# Can't start packages in anaconda on windows

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am getting a very annoying error and I can't figure out the problem. I installed Anaconda on Windows, in conda prompt:

```
conda create -n spacy_py36 python=3.6 anaconda 
>> activate spacy_py36
>> (spacy_py36) conda install -c conda-forge spacy jupyterlab gensim 
>> (spacy_py36) python -m spacy download en
>> (spacy_py36) conda install -c anaconda nltk
```

All went well, however, when I wanted to start Spyder, or jupyter, I got the following errors:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You're mixing packages from conda-forge and  , defaults channels, and that's a recipe for odd problems like this one. Please install *everything* from one or the other channel, and try again.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, surely I will try, however, I did exactly the same bust on both, Ubuntu and MacOS and everything worked well (I could start everything with no problems). Do you have any idea whether it is the windows issue? Should run the anaconda prompt as administrator or do some other “black magic”?

Comment: Mixing conda-forge and defaults should be avoided in all OSes. That you got it to work on Linux and macOS is pure luck.

Comment: Got it. Would the following lines of code install what I need properly? :

'conda create -n nlp_py36

activate nlp_py36

(nlp_py36) > conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn gensim spacy spyder pandas seaborn numpy matplotlib nltk
'

Comment: Yes, that's right.